# mobile phone calls on Huawei MediaPad

Tags: calls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I receive calls of cell phone number with a tablet?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22034/can-i-receive-calls-of-cell-phone-number-with-a-tablet)

I have Huawei MediaPad tablet. I saw in it specification that it supports GSM network. But I cannot find application to make phone calls. When I inserted SIM card and called to my phone, the call was terminated without notifications or reasons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that a device supports GSM networks doesn't mean it has call capabilities. I own a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 which also has GSM capabilities but no calling. The GSM chip is just used for mobile network data and SMS services.

Comment: What I need to have call capabilities?

Comment: Something like [Skype](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skype.raider&hl=en), [Viber](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.viber.voip&hl=en), or [Tango](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sgiggle.production&hl=en) are options. Otherwise this might not be the right device for you.